# how checking multiple field using ajax & mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

how to check multiple field using ajax & mysql
for example, I Want to check or validate if an email exist in my database
my code is

jquery_append.js

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      var count = 0;

      $("#add_btn").click(function(){
     count += 1;
       $('#container').append(
        
        '<div class="s"><tr class="records">'
        + '<td ><div id="'+count+'">No : ' + count + '</div></td></tr>'
       + '<tr class="records"><td><label>Email</label><input id="email_' + count + '" name="email_' + count + '" type="text" class="email" required><label>Nama Depan</label><input id="nama_depan_' + count + '" name="nama_depan_' + count + '" type="text"><label>Nama Belakang</label><input id="nama_belakang_' + count + '" name="nama_belakang_' + count + '" type="text"></td></tr>'
       
      
       
        + '<tr class="records"><td><label>Tipe Operasi</label><select name="tipe_operasi_' + count + '"><option value="0">-Pilih-</option></select></td><tr>'
        + '<tr class="records"><td><label>Lokasi</label><select name="lokasi_' + count + '"><option value="0">-Pilih-</option></select></td><tr>'
        + '<tr class="records"><td><label>Alamat</label><input id="alamat_' + count + '" name="alamat_' + count + '" type="text"></td><tr>'
       + '<br><tr class="records"><td><a class="remove_item" href="#" >Delete</a>'
       + '<input id="rows_' + count + '" name="rows[]" value="'+ count +'" type="hidden"></td></tr><tr><td><hr></td></tr></div>'
     );
    });

    $(".remove_item").live('click', function (ev) {
       if (ev.type == 'click') {
          $(this).parents(".s").fadeOut();
          $(this).parents(".s").remove();
         }
       });
  });
```

Comment: have you tried something?

Comment: I dont know why everybody doesnt get it. Its simple. The OP only expects us to write an entire Ajax Call for him. That's what we are  here for. Right? ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a function and trigger it on blur of your email field. Pass your email as a parameter of your function and check it into your database.

This is your email field:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" value="" />
```

This is your JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#email").blur(function(){
        var email = $("#email").val();
        if(email != ""){
            $.ajax({ 
                url: 'ajax_function_url',
                data: {email:email},
                type: 'post',
                complete: function(output) {
                    var isExist = output.responseText;
                    if(isExist === '1'){
                        alert('This email is already in use.');
                    }else{
                        alert('success!!');
                    }
                }
            });
        }else{
            alert('Email should not be empty');
        }
    });
}
```

This is your PHP function which is called by Ajax:

```
    function CheckEmailExist() {
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        if (isset($_POST['email']) && $_POST['email'] != "") {
            $sql = "SELECT id FROM `table` WHERE `email` = '" . $_POST['email'] . "'";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);
            echo mysql_num_rows($result);
        }
        exit();
    }
```

This way you can check if your data exists in your database or not via ajax.

Comment: user3533244 thank you for your answer but you have code for example because i try not working for me